# bar button not showing

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I want to use custom barbutton that will have some image.
I am doing as below code.but barbutton is not displaying.

```
 UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(nowPlayingButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

nowPlaying = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
nowPlaying.action = @selector(nowPlayingButtonClicked);
nowPlaying.target = self;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nowPlaying;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set a frame for the Button that you add to BarButton

```
   button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give image for both state as selected and normal. So then it will appear to you. It's just a hint. But try it.

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(nowPlayingButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

nowPlaying = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nowPlaying;
```